# PHRETS:GetMetadataTypes() called but unable to find GetMetadata location

Tags: rets

I'm building a RETS based application and every time I try to run the script it shows "GetMetadataTypes() called but unable to find GetMetadata location. Failed login?". I'm not sure what exactly is causing this issue.  Below is my code snippet for your review:

```
 if ($connect)
 {
     echo "  + Connected<br>\n";

     $types = $rets->GetMetadataTypes();

// check for errors
     if (!$types)
  {
            print_r($rets->Error());
     }
    else
 {
    var_dump($types);
  }
```

}

Below is the debug log for your review. 
* About to connect() to ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 107.22.214.38...
* connected
* Connected to ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com (107.22.214.38) port 80 (#0)

> GET /acc/rets/login HTTP/1.1

Host: ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com

Accept: */*

RETS-Version: RETS/1.5

User-Agent: PHRETS/1.0

Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

< Cache-Control: private

< Cache-Control: private

< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

< Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 09:00:26 GMT

< MIME-Version: 1.0

< RETS-Version: RETS/1.5

< Server: nginx/1.0.11

- Added cookie JSESSIONID="94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4" for domain ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com, path /acc, expire 0
  < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4; Path=/acc
- Replaced cookie JSESSIONID="94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4" for domain ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com, path /acc, expire 0
  < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4; Path=/acc

< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="rets@flexmls.com", qop="auth", nonce="055a98f2718db640bb49b25727b265c7", opaque="e740e530f881b719ac847f225d70ef26"

< Content-Length: 954

< Connection: keep-alive

<

- Ignoring the response-body
- Connection #0 to host ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com left intact
- Issue another request to this URL: 'http://ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com:80/acc/rets/login'
- Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (nil)
- Connected to (nil) (107.22.214.38) port 80 (#0)
- Server auth using Digest with user 'chs.rets.asolz1-i33'

> GET /acc/rets/login HTTP/1.1
>   
>   Authorization: Digest username="chs.rets.asolz1-i33", realm="rets@flexmls.com", nonce="055a98f2718db640bb49b25727b265c7", uri="/acc/rets/login", cnonce="MTUzODg1", nc=00000001, qop="auth", response="a28c686f4af4100dc6f417c013c44233", opaque="e740e530f881b719ac847f225d70ef26"

Host: ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com

Accept: */*

Cookie: JSESSIONID=94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4

RETS-Version: RETS/1.5

User-Agent: PHRETS/1.0

Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK

< Cache-Control: private

< Cache-Control: private

< Content-Type: text/xml

< Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 09:00:26 GMT

< MIME-Version: 1.0

< RETS-Version: RETS/1.5

< Server: nginx/1.0.11

- Replaced cookie JSESSIONID="94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4" for domain ctarmls2.apps.retsiq.com, path /acc, expire 0
  < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=94616DF90574A5747A5CC58526968DC4; Path=/acc

< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="rets@retsiq.com",qop="auth",nonce="1647953c3586fee2f03a44259066e02d", opaque="31b02b3042ea6"

< Content-Length: 283

< Connection: keep-alive

<

- Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact

MemberName=chs.rets.asolz1-i33

User=chs.rets.asolz1-i33,1,MEMBER,20141216152304900080000000

Broker=RETS_OFFIC

MetadataVersion=01.01.71275

MinMetadataVersion=01.01.71275

Logout=/acc/rets/logout

- Closing connection #0

Thanks

Comment: The issue is solved There was IP address restriction.

Answer (score 0):

It is the rets server issue. The server has to specify a metadata url location which is displaying in the xml response when logging via a browser which is missing for this server. Tell this concern to rets server maintenance team.